# Proving systems of nonlinear modular equations have no solution

Tags: matrices, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, matrix-equations

I have reason to suspect this system of six nonlinear modular equations has no solution for $2 < x < y < z$ even integers.
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
z(3y+2) \equiv y(3z+2) \equiv 0& \mod x\\
 z(3x+2) \equiv x(3z+2) \equiv 0& \mod y\\
x(3y+2) \equiv y(3x+2) \equiv 0& \mod z
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Remove any one and numerous solutions are easy to find, so I can't make the system any smaller.  Having no solution is also consistent with other empirical results.  But naturally I'd like a proof or a counterexample.  Since the moduli are not pairwise coprime, I don't see how the CRT can help.

Using the definition of modulus, I could transform these into a system of nonlinear equations with nine variables:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    -K_1   &2   &3y\\
    -K_2  & 3z &  2\\
    2   & -K_3   &3x\\
    3z   &-K_4  & 2\\
    2   & 3x   &-K_5\\
    3y   & 2   &-K_6
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where the Ki's are positive constants.  But this doesn't seem to get me anywhere and may actually make the problem harder.

Any hope of proving something like this? This is research, but I'm a computer scientist by training, not a mathematician.  Abstract algebra, discrete math, number theory, linear algebra etc either self-taught or learned back in the Dark Ages by candlelight.

--BF

Comment: They all reduce to some form of $2a\equiv 2b\bmod c$

Comment: Yes, but you lose information.  That reduction has plenty of solutions with the indicated constraints.  The original does not, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: Distributive law means you get $3zy$ in both of the first,  it means the difference of the terms is $2z-2y$ this must divide by  $x$ for the definition of Modular congruence to hold.

Comment: After correcting for that error I made below, I have a solution if one of the pairing of $x,y,z$ is coprime. I suppose that's not necessarily the case?

Comment: Alas no, see 2nd paragraph of post.

Comment: I think I've got it, but it's a bit lengthy so I'll need to figure out how to shorten it. Letting $d = \gcd(x/2,y/2)$ we can show that $z = 2t = cd$ for some $c$ and working out the inequalities will give $a,b,c \leq 24$, where $x=2ad,y=2bd$. Then it remains to test all the cases which is a straightforward bruteforce.

Comment: As a consequence of the proof, if we do not use the $\equiv 0 $ part of the system then there are still solutions of the form $$(x,y,z) = (2d,6d,8d),(2d,12d,20d)$$
for any positive integer $d$, and only these two classes. To get no solutions we must add the $\equiv 0 \pmod y$ part. Adding other two instead does not help since there are solutions of the types $$(x,y,z) = (2+4k,6+12k,8+16k), (6+10k,36+60k,60+100k)$$

Answer (score 1):

## **Proof outline**

1. We first simplify the system into (almost) coprime modulus using only $3$ of the $6$ equations (ignoring the $\equiv 0$ part).
2. This will allow us to derive 2 general classes of solutions.
3. We will then use a fourth equation $x(3z+2)\equiv 0 \pmod y$ to show both are not feasible, concluding the proof that there are no solutions.

---

Since $2<x<y<z$ are even integers, we let $x=2r,y=2s,z=2t$ and part of the system of equations (using the $\equiv 0$ part later) becomes
$$
\begin{align*}
2z-2y&\equiv 0 \pmod x &\implies 2t-2s &\equiv 0 \pmod r\\
2z - 2x &\equiv 0 \pmod y &\implies 2t-2r &\equiv 0 \pmod s\\
2y - 2x &\equiv 0 \pmod z &\implies 2s-2r &\equiv 0 \pmod t
\end{align*}
$$
Let $d = \gcd(s,t)$ and write $s=bd,t=cd$ so that $\gcd(b,c)=1$. Then from
$$
2s - 2r= 0 \pmod t,
$$
we get
$$
2bd - 2r \equiv 0 \pmod{cd}
$$
So that $d$ divides $2r$. Hence we let $2r = ad$. We now simplify the system of equations:
$$
\begin{align*}
2t-2s &\equiv 0 \pmod r &\implies 4t-4s &\equiv 0 \pmod{2r}&\implies 4cd-4bd &\equiv 0 \pmod{ad} &\implies 4c-4b&\equiv 0\pmod a\\
2t-2r &\equiv 0 \pmod s &\implies 2cd-ad &\equiv 0 \pmod{bd} &\implies 2c-a &\equiv 0 \pmod b\\
2s-2r &\equiv 0 \pmod t &\implies 2bd-ad &\equiv 0\pmod{cd} &\implies 2b-a &\equiv 0 \pmod c
\end{align*}
$$

Hence we get a new system
$$
\begin{align*}
4c-4b &\equiv 0 \pmod{a}\\
2c-a &\equiv 0 \pmod{b}\\
2b-a &\equiv 0 \pmod{c}
\end{align*}
$$

---

Next we prove a lemma that bounds the values of $a,b,c$:

> **Lemma.** Any solution to the system must satisfy
>   $$
> 1\leq a,b,c \leq 9
> $$

**Proof.** From the system of equations:
$$
\begin{align*}
2c - a &\equiv 0 \pmod b &\implies 2b + 2c - a &\equiv 0 \pmod b\\
2b - a &\equiv 0 \pmod c &\implies 2b + 2c - a &\equiv 0 \pmod c
\end{align*}
$$
Since $\gcd(b,c)=1$, by CRT we have
$$
2b+2c - a \equiv 0 \pmod{bc}
$$
Since $2b = 2s/d > 2r/d = a$, this means $2b+2c-a > 0$. Therefore we obtain a bound of $bc$:
$$
bc \leq 2b+2c - a < 2b+2c
$$
If $3 \leq b < c$, then
$$
(b-2)c < 2b \implies c < (2b)/(b-2) = 2 + 4/(b-2) \leq 2+4 = 6
$$
giving us a bound of $c \leq 5$. Similarly,
$$
(c-2)b < 2c \implies b < (2c)/(c-2) = 2 + 4/(c-2) \leq 2+4 = 6
$$
Hence we get $b,c \leq 5$. Using $2b > a$ then bounds $a,b,c$ as $a,b,c \leq 9$.

For the remaining case, $b=1$ or $b=2$. If $b=1$ then $2b>a$ forces $a=1$, so the system reduces to
$$
2-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{c}
$$
This forces $c=1$, contradicting $c>b$. Alternatively, if $b=2$ the system becomes
$$
\begin{align*}
4c-8 &\equiv 0 \pmod{a}\\
2c-a &\equiv 0 \pmod{2}\\
4-a &\equiv 0 \pmod{c}
\end{align*}
$$
So we see that $2$ divides $a$. Since $1\leq a < 2b = 4$, this can only be $a=2$. But now
$$
4-2 \equiv 0 \pmod c
$$
forces $c=1,2$, again contradicting $c>b$. This means $b\leq 2$ is not possible, therefore the previous bound
$$
1\leq a,b,c \leq 9
$$
is the only possible one and we are done.
$$
\tag*{$\square$}
$$

---

Now a brute force search of $1\leq a,b,c \leq 9$, conditioned on $a/2<b<c$ and $\gcd(b,c)=1$ shows that the only solutions are
$$
(a,b,c) = (1,3,5), (2,3,4)
$$
which corresponds to
$$
(x,y) = (2r,2s) = (ad,2bd) = (d,6d), (2d,6d)
$$
($z$ doesn't matter) They must satisfy one of the original equations
$$
x(3z+2) \equiv 0 \pmod y
$$
Hence we must have
$$
\begin{align*}
(d)(3z+2) \equiv 0 \pmod{6d} \implies 3z+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 6\\
(2d)(3z+2) \equiv 0 \pmod{6d} \implies 2(3z+2) \equiv 0\pmod 6
\end{align*}
$$
This is impossible $\pmod 3$, therefore there are no solutions and we are done.

Comment: Wow.  Printing out now, will take me a couple of hours to work through and understand.  But thanks in advance for the effort!

Comment: Please feel free to point out any problems or ask about any parts.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Made a mistake, this is wrong**

Let us isolate two of the equations:
$$
\begin{align*}
z(3y+2) &\equiv 0 \pmod x\\
z(3x+2) &\equiv 0 \pmod y
\end{align*}
$$

From
$$
z(3y+2)\equiv 0 \pmod x,
$$
This means $x$ divides $z(3y+2)$. Since these are positive numbers,
$$
x \leq 3yz+2z
$$
Similarly, from
$$
z(3x+2)\equiv 0 \pmod y
$$
we get
$$
y \leq 3x z+2z
$$
Now subtracting latter from former:
$$
y-x \leq 3z(x-y)
$$
Since $x < y$, LHS is greater than zero. However since $x<y$ and $0<z$, RHS is less than zero. Therefore this is impossible.

Comment: Unfortunately, your basic concept is incorrect. Using your idea, say for example you have $1 \le 4$ and $2 \le 3$. Subtracting the latter from the former, you would then get $1 \le -1$! Note you can *only* validly add inequalities, *not* subtract them. Subtracting them is equivalent to multiplying both sides of the one being subtracted by $-1$ (and, thus, reversing the inequality) first and then adding, but you then get incompatible inequalities.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks, that was a really silly mistake.

Comment: That's OK, I appreciate the effort.  Just glad it wasn't that easy :-).  I am beginning to suspect this is a hard problem.