# Son of Proving systems of nonlinear modular equations have no solution

Tags: matrices, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, nonlinear-system

This is a followup to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472686/proving-systems-of-nonlinear-modular-equations-have-no-solution#), thanks to [Yong Hao Ng](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/31788/yong-hao-ng) for his help with that.  I understand the proof now, cleaned it up and tweaked it a little bit.  Very helpful.

That problem concerned the three-variable case.  For various reasons, the answer to the four-variable case is the same.  Now comes the five variable case.  If the technique from the previous problem generalizes, I cannot yet see how.

Consider the following nonlinear modular system of equations in five variables and a parameter X:

(a2-X)[(a3+1)(a4+1)(a5+1)-1] = 0 mod a6

(a3-X)[(a4+1)(a5+1)(a6+1)-1] = 0 mod a2

(a4-X)[(a2+1)(a5+1)(a6+1)-1] = 0 mod a3

(a5-X)[(a2+1)(a3+1)(a6+1)-1] = 0 mod a4

(a6-X)[(a2+1)(a3+1)(a4+1)-1] = 0 mod a5

I conjecture this system has no solution for X=6, 6 < a2 < a3 ... < a6 for ai even.  Consistent with observations, can't find a counterexample. I have a solution for X=10, conjecture for even X >= 10 there are infinitely many solutions.  Solutions with X=8 aren't of interest.  Solutions with X=6 would be.

Proof or counterexample would be the best outcome, but a bound on any one of the ai with X=6 would be almost as good, because then the question could be answered computationally.

I've tried the technique of [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472686/proving-systems-of-nonlinear-modular-equations-have-no-solution#) below (let d = gcd of the two highest numbers, for the remaining ai express Xai as a multiple of d, get a new system based on a mutually prime pair of moduli) but with more than three variables I cannot see how to show that for the remaining ai, Xai is a multiple of d (although it very well may be true).

Tried a few different approaches, but every time I get stuck in the complexity of having so many variables. (ai+1)(aj+1)(ak+1)-1 is the sum of all products of length 1 to 3 that can be formed from aj, aj and ak, which makes things complicated.  Grateful for any suggestions, strategies to try, etc.

--BF